# UML Sequence Diagram implementing

Tags: asynchronous, uml, message, sequence-diagram

Can you please check with me if my sequence diagram is correct or not.
Sequence diagram of use cas "ADD USER"
i use a asynchronouns message and i think that it's incoreect
Please help me to correct it
[image]

Comment: Since my french is so good that I'd starve in a bistro, I can't help much. But even if I could read the words, how could I tell wrong or right if I don't know the requirements?

Answer (score 0):

The open arrow heads of your messages appropriately represent asynchronous messages (vs. plain arrows for synchronous).

What is disturbing on your diagram are the way you represent the reply messages:

- the message `2.Formulaire d'ajout` is certainly triggered as part of the system activity (aka execution specification) that processes `1.Demande formulaire d'ajout()`.  (*"demande" is a request*)
- Even if it would be generated by an independent activity (e.g. delayed processing of a message queue), it would certainly not be issued spontaneously to start a new activity on the side of the sender.
- The same logic would apply to the third activity of the administrator: I'd expect "3.Remplissage du formulaire d'ajout" being sent as part of the activity triggered by the receipt of the form.  (*"remplissage" is the filling of the form*)
- Again the same principle would still be valid for the system activity in the inner alt bloc:  the message 7 and 9 seem to be part of the processing of 6 and 8 could and not spontaneously generated at the start of a new activity.

In your outer `alt` bloc you seem to consider alternatives related to the verification message (missing mandatory fields or not).  I understand it well (fortunatly I speak french), but it is not clear what happens after the allert message.  I suppose, you'd resume the filling action.  So  I wonder, if it would not be clearer to regroup `3.remplissage formulaire d'ajout` with `champ exigés non remplis` in a `loop` bloc.  The part `Champs exigés remplis` would then continue the lifelines outside of the `loop` bloc.

As [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3379653/thomas-kilian) mentioned in the comments:  it is difficult to confirm you for sure that's correct, if we don't know the precise requirements. So in addition to the formal remarks above, here is what I understand from the remainder of your diagram:

- The inner `alt` bloc shows the processing resulting from the database activity (success or failure). Here you mean that the database does the verification and sends the message back (e.g. via db-triggers) to the system.  It's not the system who queries the database to do the checks.  Up to you to see if it meets your expectations.

Comment: the message so must be synchronous message ?

Comment: @SaberMhadhbi up to you to decide. They could be asynchronous as you've represented. But if you want them to be synchronous you could just draw plain arrows. In thi case the reply messages should be drawn with a dotted line

Comment: please can you explain for me what's the difference between synchnouns ans asynchronouns message ?

Comment: @SaberMhadhbi In a synchronous message, the sender has to wait until the receiver has finished before he continues (similar to a function call). Asynchronous means that as soon as the message is sent, the sender can continue its work without waiting.  Here you'll find some additional infos: http://www.tracemodeler.com/articles/a_quick_introduction_to_uml_sequence_diagrams/